# Return the address of a cell that matches a search and copy everything in the next X rows to another sheet

Tags: excel, search, copy

I have a sheet in which I need to find a row that has a certain phrase "Beginning of data" in it's first column.
I then have to copy all rows up to a row that contains the phrase "End data" into a separate sheet.
Any help with this VBA macro or use of Excel functions is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This code will search column A of Sheet1 for "Beginning of data" and "End of Data" and then copy A-I for those rows and the rows inbetween them into Sheet2 starting at cell A1.

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim RowBeg As Long
Dim RowEnd As Long

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Select

Selection.Find(What:="Beginning of data", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        
RowBeg = ActiveCell.row
        
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Select
        
Selection.Find(What:="End of Data", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        
RowEnd = ActiveCell.row

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowBeg, 1).Resize(RowEnd - RowBeg + 1, 9).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")


End Sub
```

Comment: This copies only a specific column over. I need to copy data in Columns A to I for all the rows between "Beginning of data" and "End of data". Sorry I did not specify this accurately earlier.

Comment: Do you always just copy columns a-i and beginning/end of data mark the rows to copy? Are beginning/end of data just in column a, or all columns? If you post a screenshot I'll rewrite it this afternoon.

Comment: Correct. Always A to I.

Comment: I'm new here how do I post a screenshot or upload a file?

Comment: Are beginning/end of data in column a?

Comment: Yes Column A has "Beginning of data" and "End of Data"

Comment: Did you need anything else?

Comment: I've updated my original post. Let me know if you need anything else!